# How do I make an interactive label with ggplot pie chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph

I currently have a donut chart that shows a count of vessels by length buckets (in feet) and the percentage of the donut these buckets make when you hover over different areas of the chart.

However, I would like to make it so the label I have that populates the center of the donut chart updates to reflect the percentage of the pie, `'pct'` value in the code, while I hover over different sections of the donut.

Currently, the label is just set to my first bucket length of data. Help on how to make is label interactive is appreciated.

```r
 donut_data <- data.frame(type = c("1000 + FT", "850-1,000 FT", "700-850 FT", "500-750 FT", "300-500 FT", "100-300FT", "75-100 FT", "50-75 FT", "35-50 FT", "25-35 FT", "0-25 FT"), value = c(2240,3645,3895,18902,8315,71074,13398,62709,264055, 407763, 582255), pct = c("0.2%","0.3%","0.3%","1.3%","0.6%","4.9%","0.9%","4.4%","18.4%","28.4%","40.5%")) %>%
  mutate(
    percentage = value / sum(value),
    hover_text = paste0(type, ": ", value, ": ", pct)
  ) %>%
  mutate(percentage_label = paste0(round(100 * percentage, 1), "%"))

donut_plot <- ggplot(donut_data, aes(y = value, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar_interactive(
    aes(x = 1, tooltip = hover_text),
    width = 0.3,
    stat = "identity",
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    label = donut_data[["percentage_label"]][donut_data[["type"]]=="1000 + FT"],
    size = 20,
    color = "black"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1000 + FT" = "blue", "850-1,000 FT" ="red", "700-850 FT" = "magenta", "500-750 FT"= "pink", "300-500 FT" = "gray", "75-100 FT" = "gold", "50-75 FT" = "yellow",  "35-50 FT"= "blue", "25-35 FT"="gray", "0-25 FT"="red")) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()

ggiraph(ggobj = donut_plot)
```